# How to create a figure note below the figure caption in r markdown and bookdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I am struggling to create a figure note below the figure caption in `r markdown` and `bookdown`. The figure note I want looks like below. This figure is from `(Greenstone and Hanna 2014)`. My figure actually is a 
`r` plot. The note should be the same length as the figure width and automatically break the line. Any ideas???

[image]

Comment: Did you try fig.cap in the code block parameters?

Comment: @user12256545 Yes I tried. `fig.cap` does not do the job. It just takes notes as a caption. What I wanted is the note shown in the figure above.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using a format that goes through LaTeX (e.g. `pdf_book` or `pdf_document`), this is possible.  I don't know if there's a way to do it with HTML output. (But does that move figures around?  Maybe plain text below the figure is enough).  The idea is to enter the LaTeX code to
start and end the figure yourself, and include the note within that block. Here's an example, based on the standard `pdf_document` example.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:  Figure \ref{fig:pressure}.
```{=latex}
\begin{figure}[t]
```
```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```
```{=latex}
\caption{Air quality monitors across India. \label{fig:pressure}}
\textit{Notes:} Dots denote cities with monitoring stations
under India's National Ambient Air Monitoring Programme
(NAAMP).  Geographical data are drawn from MIT's Geodata
Repository.
\end{figure}
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Comment: Hi. I wanted to similar thing but in my case the note is coming above the caption and is center aligned? How can I (1) left align; (2) keep it below caption; and (3) decrease text size of this note?

Comment: Hi please ignore (1) and (3) as I was able to do it with required latex code in the latex chunks. (2) is still a problem

Comment: @Dayne:  you should post a new question showing what you did, and someone will tell you how to fix it.

Comment: thanks for replying. I was thinking I'd putting separately but then tried something and it worked out :). Anyway +1 for this ans

Comment: This seems to cause the cross referenced label to break in a strange way... it appears as ?? but still correctly links to the figure in the document

Comment: @Reilstein:  That kind of thing happens in LaTeX if you don't run `pdflatex` enough times.  I think `knitr` uses `latexmk`; maybe it doesn't know that it needs to process the file 2 or more times?  You should post a full question about this, and someone will probably tell you how to fix it.

Comment: @user2554330 thank you. I tried every solution on the internet and finally discovered a stupid mistake: I put the \label in front of the \caption which is incorrect.